# Json response is not loaded in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

I tried solutions given for this problem. But still, it is not working. I feel JSON response is not in the right format.

Have implemented JQGrid in struts2. Create a user list in action and returned as json type using result type as json in struts.xml.

This is the Json i obtained,

```
{"JSON":"success","userList":[{"fName":"abi","lName":"babu"},{"fName":"abi1","lName":"babu1"},{"fName":"abi2","lName":"babu2"},{"fName":"abi3","lName":"babu3"},{"fName":"abi4","lName":"babu4"},{"fName":"abi5","lName":"babu5"},{"fName":"abi6","lName":"babu6"}]}
```

The JSP page is,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
            url: "json-table",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['fName','lName'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'fName',index:'fName', key:true, width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
                {name:'lName',index:'lName', width:100,editable:true},
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[3,6],
            loadonce: true,
            pager: '#navGrid',
            sortname: 'fName',
            sortorder: "asc", 
            height: "auto", //210,
            width:600,
            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                var getID = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', id, 'fName');
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:"JQ GRID"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just include `jsonReader` parameter which corresponds the format of your input data:

```js
jsonReader: {root: "userList", repeatitems: false}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Abinaya.htm).